# Is there any difference between these forms : returnType vs returnType &?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, return-type

Consider these free standalone functions:

```
          std::vector<int>& f();   //reference
          std::vector<int>  g();   //value

/*const*/ std::vector<int>&  f1 = f();  //reference
          std::vector<int>   f2 = f();  //value

/*const*/ std::vector<int>&  g1 = g();  //reference
          std::vector<int>   g2 = g();  //value
```

Is there any difference between :

- f() and g(). Its easy question, but still I would like to hear some detail commentary on them, as it might help understanding the answer of the next questions.
- f1 and f2. Will they be same original object from f(), or f2 will be a copy of the original? Uncommenting `const` will make any difference?
- g1 and g2. Will they be same original object from g(), or g2 will be a copy of the original? Uncommenting `const` will make any difference?

What if `f()` and `g()` are member functions, and each returns member data, not some local variable? Will it make any difference in the answer of the above questions?

Please try including all the pitfalls and important points in your answer, and don't consider RVO or any other optimization by compiler. I want to know what C++ is, not what compilers do. If you talk about optimizations, please explicitly mention it, so that I dont mix language features with compiler features.

Comment: Copy elision is a language feature, it's explicitly called out in the standard.

Comment: @Ben: That is required, or the compiler *optionally* can do that?

Comment: @Nawaz: Under certain conditions, it's unspecified whether the copy constructor (or move constructor) is called.  It has to be called out in the standard, because elision changes the observable behavior of the program, this optimization would not be allowed under the as-if rule.

Comment: @Ben: `as-if` rule? that means its not required, and it is optionally done by compilers, right? A compiler which doesn't perform `copy-elision` can still be called standard-conformant.

Comment: @Nawaz: Certainly.  But a program that relies on not having copy-elision is not well-defined, just like a program that modifies a variable twice between sequence points.

Comment: @Ben: `But a program that relies on not having copy-elision is not well-defined`....  Why?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because the standard explicitly does not allow you to rely on the copy-constructor (or move-constructor) side effects in such a situation.

Comment: @Ben: Why? If copy-ctor doesn't work properly, that would imply *copy-ctor* is wrongly implemented, or if its the default one, then its not enough for your purpose.

Comment: @Nawaz: If a program is relying on side effects which the standard says may or may not take place, the behavior is not well-defined.

Comment: @Ben: Which side effect you're taking about?

Comment: @Nawaz: Any observable side effects caused by the copy or move constructor.

Comment: @Ben: Even if the copy-ctor is implemented correctly?

Comment: @Nawaz: It depends on what you mean by "correctly".  A well designed copy constructor will simply copy the object, and have no side effects which aren't reversed by the destructor.  In this case it will be fine.  It's when you add external side effects that you lose any guarantee that your program will work as designed.

Comment: @Nawaz: Like I said earlier, it's like a program which relies on order of unsequenced operations.  A conforming compiler can generated multiple different behaviors, since the standard leaves them unspecified.

Comment: @Ben: By "correctly" I meant the same thing what you mean by "well-designed". If a well-designed copy-ctor will not have side-effects, then is it not the problem with the implementation of copy-ctor?

Comment: @Nawaz: I agree there's a problem with the design of any copy-ctor that produces observable side effects.  But ultimately it's up to the main program to not rely on any side effects that do exist.

Answer (score 8):

`f()` returns a reference to an object; returning from it does not copy any object.  `g()` returns a copy of an object, at least conceptually.

```
std::vector<int>&  f1 = f();  //reference
```

`f1` refers to the object to which `f()` returned a reference.  No copies are made.  Const-qualification of the reference does not make a difference here (as far as copying is concerned; obviously it affects what can be done with the object).

```
std::vector<int>   f2 = f();  //value
```

`f2` is a copy of the object to which `f()` returned a reference.

```
std::vector<int>&  g1 = g();  //reference
```

This is invalid.  A non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary object.

If the reference is const-qualified, then this line is effectively the same as the next line:  a copy of the object returned by `g()` is made, the reference is bound to that copy, and that copy is given the lifetime of the reference (it is destroyed when the reference is "destroyed").

```
std::vector<int>   g2 = g();  //value
```

`g2` is a copy of the object returned by `g()`.  Whether a copy is made (and how many copies may be made) depends on compiler optimizations.

> What if `f()` and `g()` are member functions, and each returns member data, not some local variable?

If `f()` returns a reference to a local variable then the program is incorrect and yields undefined behavior if you attempt to use the reference because the referred-to object ceases to exist when the function returns.

If `f()` returns a reference to a member variable, a dynamically allocated object, or an object with static or thread local storage duration, then the reference is valid for the lifetime of that object (or to another object of the same type constructed at the same location in memory as the object to which the reference was returned, though the utility of this is limited to a select few scenarios).

It doesn't matter what `g()` returns because a copy is always made (at least conceptually).